# Excel - How to add words to an Excel IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

I am creating a spreadsheet for a Dungeons and Dragons game that I run to help measure initiative and turn orders.

The formula I'm trying to do is to convert the rounds passed into real time.
1 Round being 6 seconds, 10 rounds being 1 minute.

I think the math is fine, the problem is adding the words "Seconds" when the value of Rounds passed is equal to 2-9, and greater than 10.

This is the formula I have now:

```
=IF(I3=10,"1 Minute",IF(I3=1,"6 Seconds",IF(I3>1,I3*6+" Seconds")))
```

(I3 being the Rounds Passed cell)

Comment: OK so what exactly is wrong with your current formula?

Comment: I suspect the +" Seconds" is incorrect, I get "#VALUE!" when I use it

Comment: See @urdearboy 's answer - but also, if l3 anything other than 10 (e.g 50) it will give you the value in seconds (300 in this example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build strings with the `&` operator, not the `+` operator.

```
=IF(I3=10,"1 Minute",IF(I3=1,"6 Seconds",IF(I3>1,I3*6 & " Seconds")))
```